# Mock a `puts` to a file in Rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a silly "queue-class[1]" with the following method, that I want to spec out with Rspec. I am not interested in testing if writing to the file-system works (It works, my computer works) but in whether or not the correct data gets written away.

```
def write transaction
  File.open("messages/#{@next_id}", "w") {|f| f.puts transaction }
  @next_id += 1
end
```

The spec for testing this is:

```
describe TransactionQueue do
  context "#write" do
    it "should write positive values" do
      open_file = mock File
      open_file.stub(:puts)

      File.any_instance.stub(:open).and_yield(open_file)
      File.any_instance.should_receive(:open)
      open_file.should_receive(:puts).with("+100")

      @queue = TransactionQueue.new
      @queue.write("+100")
    end
  end
end
```

Running this, fails, because my Mocks never receive the expected "open" and "puts" messages.

Can I mock `File` this way? Did I use the `any_instance` correctly; is my attempt to stub a "block-yield" correct?

I'd rather not use extra gems like FakeFS when it can be avoided; this is not so much about getting it to work; bu mostly about actually understanding what is going on. Hence my attempt to avoid extra gems/layers of complexity.

[1] Class is from [The Cucumber Book](http://pragprog.com/book/hwcuc/the-cucumber-book); but these tests have littel to do with Cucumber itself. I somehow broke the code when following the book; and want to find out what, by writing unit-tests for the parts that the book does not write tests for: the helper classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not "any instance" of the `File` class that you expect to receive the `open` method; it's the `File` class itself:

```
  File.stub(:open).and_yield(open_file)
  File.should_receive(:open)
```

Furthermore, don't use both a stub and an expectation. If you want to verify that `File.open` is actually called:

```
  File.should_receive(:open).and_yield(open_file)
```

If you merely want to stub the `open` method *in case* it gets called, but don't want to require it as behaviour of the `@queue.write` method:

```
  File.stub(:open).and_yield(open_file)
```

(This is from memory, I haven't used RSpec for a few months.)

Comment: stub is deprecated in the latest version of Rspec.  For anyone wants to do it, please try this one:`allow(File).to receive(:open).and_yield(open_file)`